# How to now if the OH group on the C5 carbon of a cyclic sugar is up or down in Fischer Projection

Tags: molecular-structure

I know when using fischer projection I have to look if it's a D or L configuration. if it's D: up = right and down = left and if it's L: up = left and down = right. I think the concept is clear to me, however I dont't know if the OH group on the C5 carbon atom is pointing up or down. For example: 
[image]

When I have to draw those cyclic molecules to fischer projection I never know if the OH group which will be shown in the fischer projection (not in the clyic structure because it's a hemi-acetal then) is pointing up or down. **What is the rule for this?**

I want to get this: 
[image]

But I don't know how to know the side of the circled OH group

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Generally, a Fisher projection is drawn vertically with the OHs on the left and right. The carbonyl appears at the top. Up and down only make sense if there is a ring. But the C5 carbon doesn't have an OH. The C1 carbon has an OH which is clearly up, but in the Fisher projection, that's the carbonyl carbon so there is no stereochemistry _in the projection_. Usually, this OH is in the axial position because of the anomeric effect from the adjacent ether's lone pair. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer_projection

Comment: I updated my question hopefully it clear know @Zhe

Comment: I think it's as simple as L for left and D for right... I'm not sure what you mean by up or down still. The OH you've circled in red is the O that's in the ring. The other OH of the hemiacetal is from the carbonyl (that's the one pointing up in the ring on the right).  It could be down as well. That is still the same Fisher projection.

Comment: What I mean when you have a D Sugar the rule is in the Fischer projection of the linear form OH pointing to the left ==> up in cyclic and OH pointing to the right ==> down in cyclic. However how can you determine to which side to OH is pointing on the 5th C if you don't know if it is pointing up or down (and if you don't know if the cyclic form is a D or L) @Zhe

Comment: Your question is complicated by the fact that, in your example, the placement of  C-5 hydroxyl in the Fisher projection can't change because it is D. I think the main issue is that you need to learn how to convert a Fisher projection into the ring form and vice versa. I can't tell you explicitly up or down because it matters how you draw the ring in the L- form. To my knowledge, there is no canonical form, but I might be wrong there...

Comment: I just found my answer here: http://forums.studentdoctor.net/threads/l-or-d-sugar-from-ring.1090022/ maybe you are intersted in reading it. 
For the Haworth projection:
 If the -CH2OH substituent is RIGHT of the anomeric carbon, it's D.
If the -CH2OH substituent is LEFT of the anomeric carbon, it's L. @Zhe

Comment: I'm not sure right or left make sense in a Haworth projection. Honestly, I'm a bit lost on what your specific confusion is because I just think about this in terms of stereochemistry as I was trained to do as an organic chemist. With that in mind, specific mnemonics that involve relating three things aren't particularly helpful. Come to chat if you need more of a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The OH group you've circled is always on the right hand side for D-sugars and on the left for L-sugars as its position is in the very definition of D/L sugars.